# The compilation of the compiler could affect the compiled programs?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

Probably my question sounds weird, but my point is: i have to compile a program using GCC, if i compile GCC from the source i will get a slight edge in terms of performances from a software compiled with the fresh new GCC? What I should expect?

Comment: No. Compilation is a deterministic process.

Comment: You don't say what architecture you have, what compiler you have, or what compiler you propose to build. Rebuilding the exact same compiler with the exact same options will do nothing, but an upgrade is a different story.

Answer (score 5):

1. You won't get any faster programs out of a compiler built with optimizing flags. Since a program is the compilers' output, and optimizations don't change the output of a correct program, the programs stay the same.
2. You might, however, profit from new available options if your distributor ships an incomplete compiler. Look through the GCC manual for any options you want to enable (like certain target architecture variants), and if you can't enable them in your current compiler build, there might be potential in a custom-built compiler. However, it is unlikely that it's *worth* it.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you're building a newer version of gcc, or enabling cloog, graphite, etc.

Comment: But that can make a difference, which is usually small (a few percents)

Answer (score 0):

the performance difference usually is nothing or is negligible.

in a very rare, really very rare cases you can see noticeable difference, but not always performance improvement. degradation is possible too.